# Как сделать массив и поместить его в таблицу

Tags: html, jquery

Есть форма со строками. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В строках один select и inputы со значениями. Как Перебрать каждую строку, получить оттуда значения select option:selected и input и поместить в массив.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что пока получилось https://codepen.io/igix/pen/MNadVO

```js
var data = [];

$(".calc_row").each(function (index, el){
     data.push([el].map(function(){ 

          return this.value;

    }));

  });

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calc_row row">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" value="11">
    <input type="text" value="12">
    <input type="text" value="13">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="calc_row row">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <select>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" value="14">
    <input type="text" value="15">
    <input type="text" value="16">
  </div>
</div>
```

А потом уже сформировать простую html таблицу из этого массива.
Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Не совсем понятно: где исходные данные, что необходимо выполнить, и что должно получиться? С чем возникли сложности?

Comment: Есть верстка. Нужно получить значения selet и input и добавить их в массив. У меня получилось перебрать .calc_row , а дальше из этих элементов вытащить все значения input и select и поместить в массив. Вроде все очень подробно описано. Т.е. я так понимаю, нужно тут data.push([el] как-то добавить поиск только по input и select

Comment: Используйте [`serializeArray`](https://api.jquery.com/serializearray/). Зачем вы у блочных элементов пытаетесь отыскать `value`?

Comment: Мне нужен массив из этих данных, чтобы их потом вывести в таблицу html. Фото с массивом, который мне нужен, есть выше.

Comment: @РустамГимранов ему вчера на toster готовое сделали

Comment: Не сделали на jquery и не работает, если мою разметку html сделать.

Comment: @РустамГимранов а ответ он отметил решением : https://toster.ru/q/650701

Comment: Да, спасибо ему за помощь, т.к. его код работает, но он не совсем мне подходил. Он сразу вошел в курс дела и отписал решение, в отличии от некоторых...

Comment: @Alex если его код работает тогда для чего этот вопрос ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
'use strict';

let data = [];

function retrieval(node) {

  node.each((i, elem) => {
    let arr = [];
    elem = $(elem);
    arr.push(elem.find('select option:selected').val());
    elem.find('input').each((i, elem) => {
      arr.push($(elem).val());
    });
    data.push(arr);
  });

}

retrieval($('.calc_row.row'));

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calc_row row">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" value="11">
    <input type="text" value="12">
    <input type="text" value="13">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="calc_row row">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <select>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" value="14">
    <input type="text" value="15">
    <input type="text" value="16">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы гений!!! Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Alex, всегда пожалуйста)